# How to use a LP solver to solve this problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to use a LP solver (doesn't matter which one) to solve this linear problem:

$\mbox{Maximize }\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N z_{ij} 
$

subject to:
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^N a_i=1\\
&\sum_{j=1}^N b_j=1\\
&z_{ij}\le a_i\quad \forall i,j=1,\cdots,N\\
&z_{ij}\le b_j\quad \forall i,j=1,\cdots,N\\
\end{align*}

For this goal I need to write that in the standard form of

Minimize $H^Tx$

subject to $A^Tx \leq a; B^T x = b, lb \leq x \leq ub$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to do this for small $N$, $N=1,2,3$?

Comment: @andre Yes, I wrote that for N=2 and now I think I know what I should do. Thanks.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP